# Getting the value of autofilled inputs - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, autofill

So, as some browsers auto-fill sign in forms, it causes an issue with my interactive placeholders. The placeholder is a `<span>` element with some text in, which moves above the input itself when focussed. Upon the browser inserting the data it has 'remembered', how would I be able to detect its presence, and it's value?

Please note, that it is the auto-completed value of the input which I wish to grab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code, I have managed to achieve the result I wished for:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($('#input').val());
});
```

Using a timeout allowed the browser to load itself prior to the code requesting data from it.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. Timing/Order of Operations seems to have been the issue then.

Comment: Nice approach, but in order to work for my case, I had to specify the time... Just added 50 or 100 mS: setTimeout(function() { console.log($('#input').val()); },100);

Comment: setTimeOut() is not working for me. I tried up to 3 seconds delay.

Comment: In Chrome, an autofilled value only becomes accessible by JavaScript after a user interaction on the page for some reason. That's why I use `$('body').click();` to make the value "real", else you receive an empty string. Since this does _not_ work for password fields, I use `autocomplete="new-password"` for the password field, so users will have to fill in a new password.

Answer (score 0):

Give the span an ID and run the text() method on it. Without any parameters it works as a getter.

```
var yourtext = $('#somespan').text();
```

If it was an actual textfield instead of a span, you would get the contents with the .val() method.

```
var yourtext = $( "#foo" ).val();
```

Comment: How would I find the value of the input though?

Comment: I've tried this before posting here. The answer you've provided for the input doesn't appear to work with the auto-completed value, it just returns an empty value.

Comment: Run the method above that applies and it will get the text. You can access the text once it is set to the "yourtext" variable like:

$( "#someothertextfield" ).val(yourtext);

Comment: `<input>` elements don't have `.text()` responses, as it's the value. And as explained, using the `.val()` method returns nothing, which is due to the browser inserting the value to the field.

Comment: Consider order of operations. Are the autopopulated fields populated on DOM load, or after some other action is performed. If your trying to access the text before it populates, then you are going to return an empty var.

Comment: I have found a way to use the `setTimeout` method to find the value. I will be posting an answer.

Comment: val() is not working. Even after timeout. Did you find solution