# Chrome autofill values not able to reflect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, autofill

I have the below very simple form:

```
<form action="goto.html" method="post" validate>
            <input type="text" name="username"  required>
            <br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" required>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
 </form>
```

This form is being auto filled in chrome but in jQuery when i do::-

```
console.log($('[name="username"]').val())
```

I get no value at all, even tried the following:

```
setInterval( function(){
        console.log('value is ::-')      
        console.log($('[name="username"]').val())      
    }, 500 );
```

Unless you click inside the browser the value will not show , once you click the correct value is outputted in the console.

Even if i artificially trigger a click like so:

```
setTimeout( function() {
        $('body')
            .trigger('click');
    } , 3000 );
```

The setInterval will still log blanks , unless i actually click in the browser.

Any workaround for this ? Found a similar issue [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098975/getting-the-value-of-autofilled-inputs-jquery), but the solutions mentioned don't work.

Comment: Use `val()` instead of `text()`. Not sure why that is happening in Chrome, most likely because `text()` isn't really the standard way for you to be pulling values on an input field from the get go

Comment: why do you use .text(), try .val()

Comment: `.text()` returns text values between elements. Not the values of input fields. I'm actually surprised it returns what you expect after clicking..

Comment: @AbanaClara This is not bug! , `text()` totally different than `val()`

Comment: @Pedram Sorry man not a jQuery wizard. But the post says Chrome so I assumed it behaves differently on other browsers

Comment: @AbanaClara yes used val() as well before i switched to ```text()```

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, Chrome doesn't actually fill them in on page load. It only "shows" the values to the user and waits for user interaction to confirm filling them in. At least that's what it does for me when a site needs my address data.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Any error in error log?

Comment: @icecub That sounds legitimate. I've had a scenario where I couldn't modify the css of the autofill text in Chrome no matter what I do, unless after I click on them. Sounds like your explanation is why it was happening

Comment: @icecub confirm how ? by just clicking on the document ? in my case i see the values filled in and nothing changes visually when i click on the document , but once i click the value automatically logs in the console correctly

Comment: @Pedram nope , no errors

Comment: I'm not that formilliar with the internal workings of Chrome. But it does make sense to me. I can have forms automaticly submit themselves without user interaction. Imagine me making an address form on my website and Chrome recognises it. I would be able to gain your data without your permission if Chrome would actually fill out the data.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik do you have any other input or text areas with name="username" ?

Answer (score 3):

There exists a hacky solution which I found a time ago, but I don't recall where.
It works because Javascript is able to track the autofill CSS animation in Chrome.

The CSS part:

```
@keyframes onAutoFillStart {  from {/**/}  to {/**/}}
@keyframes onAutoFillCancel {  from {/**/}  to {/**/}}

.my-input:-webkit-autofill {
    animation-name: onAutoFillStart;
    /* VERY slow dummy animation --> */
    transition: background-color 50000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.my-input:not(:-webkit-autofill) {
    animation-name: onAutoFillCancel;
}
```

The Javascript/JQuery part:

```
$(document).on('animationstart', '.my-input', function(event) {
    var input = $(event.target).closest('.my-input');
    switch(event.originalEvent.animationName) {
        case 'onAutoFillStart':
            console.log(input.val());
            // ... do some other stuff
            break;   
        case 'onAutoFillCancel':
            if(input.val() == '') {
                console.log(input.val());
                // ... do some other stuff
            }
    }
});
```

[EDIT] I found the original source here [here](https://medium.com/@brunn/detecting-autofilled-fields-in-javascript-aed598d25da7)

Comment: I'm very curious if this solves the issue. If it does, well done!

Comment: @Benni , if inside the click handler i add an alert() i get the alert , but not the `.val()` , that remains just blank.. ! some really weird behavior